# How to move Sublime Text’s build window to the right side of the window?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I recently installed Sublime Text and it is on the right side. It's not moving to the center.

[image]

I can't move/drag it to the center, even if I uninstall and reinstall it. Nothing works.

Comment: You have not provided important information, for example what is your operating system? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Right click on the top bar of the application (where the Sublime logo is sitting).
- Click "Move".
- Use your keyboard's arrow keys to move the window into a more central position.